# HTML/CSS/JavaScript unknown approach to a menu that needs a specific width and resize to this width

Tags: javascript, css, menu, html

I want to make a menu like this on the website im coding and I don't know how to approach this. The padding/margins on left and right should resize so that the menu has a specific width all the time etc 700px in this case. I don't know if I should search a solution in CSS styling, in JavaScript or both, which one is the easiest?

[image]

```
<div id="footerMenu">
                       <ul>
                       <li><a href="tools.php?tool=galeria">O nás</a></li>
                       <li><a href="tools.php?tool=galeria">Partneri</a>
                       <li><a href="tools.php?tool=galeria">Reklama</a>
                       <li><a href="tools.php?tool=galeria">Kontakt</a>
               <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li><li><a href="tools.php">Nástroje</a></li>                           </ul>
                   </div>
```

This is the code, and the CSS I tried to add and didn't work

```
#footerMenu
{
width: 640px;
margin: 0 auto;

display:block;
}
#footerMenu a
{
text-decoration: none;
display:block;
float:left;
border:0;
}
#footerMenu ul
{
list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: CSS is meant for that: `div#menu{margin: 0 auto; width: 700px;}`

Answer (score 0):

Give your menu a specific width per CSS. After that, you can tell your menu element to auto align margin left and right, so the element will keep its width and the margin on each site will scale to center your element.

```
#menu {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Your menu must be 'display: inline' oder 'inline-block', not 'block'.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is by CSS:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        div#MainNavigation { width: 700px; margin: 0 auto; }
        div#MainNavigation img { display:block;float:left;border:0; }
        </style> 
    </head> 
    <body>  
        <div id="MainNavigation">Main Navigation <img src="pic1.gif" alt="" /><img src="pic2.gif" alt="" /></div>
    </body>
</html>
```